# Regex: match a word in a string but only when line doesn't contain a slash

Tags: regex, string

I want to match a word in a string, but only when the string doesn't contain  `//`

**Example:** Match the word `books`

This should match:

`I read books`.

This should not match.

`// I read books`.

To match the word, I have created this regex:

`(?<=.)books(?=\s*)`

But how do I ignore strings that contains `//`?

**Additional info:**

- `//` are always in front of the word that i would like to match.
- `//` are not always at the beginning of the string. Leading
  whitespaces are possible.
- I want to match the word so that I can replace it in the next step.
- I want to use it in the Replace in Files function of Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: ^ *//.*text      will match any string with the word 'text' and leading with //.  The ^ will match: Begin of line

Comment: It can be done, but not for the edge case of matching only the first `"book"` of `"This is a book // another book"`. Can this case be eliminated? ie is it known that the word only appears (possibly multiple times) either before or after `//` in any given line?

Comment: @KMS: I removed my comments, undelete yours if you wish.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did

Comment: I meant **un**delete the *answer* of yours.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiktorStribiżew wrote the solution to my question in a comment.

The solution: `(?<!//.*?)(books|spoons|shelves)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Variable length negative lookbehinds are allowed. What a pity, I had a solution lined up without them. `^(?:[^\/]*(?:\/(?!\/))|)*[^\/]*(books)`. With them @Wiktors answer is of course more efficient.